# Как исправить или выполнить проверку на наличие файла/директории?

Tags: php

Использую автозагрузку классов:

```
<?php ## Постраничная навигация по папке
// Временная автозагрузка классов
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    require_once("pager/src/{$class}.php");
});

$obj = new ISPager\DirPager(new ISPager\PagesList(), 'photos', 3, 2);

// Содержимое текущей страницы
foreach ($obj->getItems() as $img) {
    echo "<img src='$img' /> ";
}

// Постраничная навигация
echo "<p>$obj</p>";
```

Но приложение падает с ошибкой:

> ```
> ( ! ) Warning: require_once(pager/src/ISPager\DirPager.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/php.xxx/composer/dir.php on line 4
> Call Stack
> #   Time    Memory  Function    Location
> 1   0.0001  392832  {main}( )   .../dir.php:0
> 2   0.0001  394000  spl_autoload_call ( )   .../dir.php:7
> 3   0.0001  394048  {closure:/var/www/php.xxx/composer/dir.php:3-5}( )  .../dir.php:7
>
> ( ! ) Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'pager/src/ISPager\DirPager.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/php.xxx/composer/dir.php on line 4
> ```

---

Как исправить данную ошибку?

Comment: Неужели так сложно отформатировать вопрос, добавить описание?

Comment: "pager/src/ISPager\DirPager.php" - вроде проблема очевидна, ниже уже ответили

Answer (score 1):

Нужно заменить все левые слеши на правые. Примерно так:

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $class = str_replace("\\", "/", $class);
require_once("pager/src/{$class}.php");
});
```